# How to automatically append a command to a file when called in a shell?

Tags: bash, package-management, logs, pacman

I'd like to keep track of all the programs I'm installing, so every time a command contains `pacman -S` (important space after -S) I'd like bash to append the command string to a file. Currently I'm using a function but it's annoying because I have to go to history and brace the line with the function and quotes. I could grep history but the general purpose solution would be handy.

Is there a way to do that automatically in a single step install&log ?

Comment: Doesn't `/var/log/pacman.log` contain what you want?

Comment: @StephenHarris no I want to append the command string into a file so I can run it if I reinstall linux, also I'll use this method not only for pacman, but also for aliases (automatic update of bashrc) etc

Comment: What do you means that you have a function, but you have to "go to the history and brace the line"? What does your function actually do?

Comment: @DarkHeart `aa () { echo $1 >> /home/logfile; }` so when I have a command I want to log I just go `aa "command"`. Still annoying, I can define a keyboard macro to brace it quickly but sometimes when the command contains quotes it can conflict with the bracing quotes.

Comment: You could create a shell-script, named `~/bin/pacman` (and add `~/bin` to `$PATH`, if it isn't yet), which would do what you want and call the actual `pacman` command by full path.

Comment: Yet better, Pacman tracks which packages were installed explicitly. Although I don't remember the exact command, possibly `pacman --query --explicit` may be used to retrieve the list.

Comment: or create the script in /usr/local/bin

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are trying to accomplish is very hard if not impossible, even when you can create a wrapper function to do what you want and an alias to call the wrapper instead of the actual command it all goes wrong because you usually run `sudo pacman -S` and sudo breaks all functions and aliases by switching contexts.

But not all is lost, you can list all packages explicitly installed with `pacman -Qe`, so if at any time you wish to reinstall the system or copy the environment to another machine you can get the list to a file, transfer the file to the target machine and run pacman to install all packages.

To make the file:

```
pacman -Qe | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | tr "\n" " " >the-file.txt
```

- `pacman -Qe`: Lists all explicitly installed packages.
- `cut -d ' ' -f 1`: is to remove the package versions and keep the names only.
- `tr "\n" " "`: is to change newlines to spaces.
- `>the-file.txt`: Is to redirect the output to a file, feel free to change the file name and path to your needs.

This will output a space separated list to the-file.txt, you then transfer the file to the target machine and run:

```
sudo pacman -Sy - <the-file.txt
```

Voila, pacman is installing all packages from the list and you will get the same result.

You can also add the `--needed` argument to pacman so it wont reinstall up-to-date packages `pacman -S --needed ...`.

And if you are doing the new machine remotely you can skip the file transfer and just pipe the results to ssh and it will carry on to the remote machine:

```
pacman -Qe | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | tr "\n" " " | ssh -t user@host "sudo pacman -S --needed -"
```

- With `-t` ssh allocates a pseudo terminal, otherwise sudo will fail.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `bash`:

```
trap `echo $BASH_COMMAND | fgrep "pacman - S" >> /home/logfile
```

You'll also want it in your `.bash_profile` or similar so it runs for every interactive shell.

Of course, this only captures the things you typed into `bash`, not anything that was executed in some other way, such as a front-end running `pacman` in the background.

Keep in mind that this could really hamper performance (running an `fgrep` for every other command you run), so while this answers your question, it's not necessarily the best way to meet your objective of tracking packages.

See also: https://superuser.com/q/175799

If you are using `zsh` instead, look up the `preexec` function in the `zsh` manual.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [sudosh2](https://github.com/squash/sudosh2) for logging of your entire command history with replay. This might do what you want.

Comment: Although this may solve the issue, it would be nice if you could expand on how to actually use `sudosh2` to do that.